# How many labels does Google Cloud Vision have?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I think Google Cloud Vision has awesome accuracy and by API, it is very easy to use. But I don't know how many teacher labels it has. Because of this, it can be sometimes difficult to efficiently use scores and compare with other outputs.

On the official document, I could't find the description about the teacher label list or something. 
Anyone knows how many teacher label it has and the rules about the labels?(I felt it has some hierarchical rules.)

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to the question? I'm curious to!

Comment: I couldn't reach the answer and find the way.